# What do I get from recordset.Fields(0)?

Tags: vba, ms-access, field, recordset

I am new to VBA and I have to understand a Code somebody else wrote. This is what she set for her variables:

```
Sub LTMovementSum1(y As Long, strStoreArea As String)
    Dim recTmp As DAO.Recordset
    Dim lngTotalLTagg As Long
    lngTotalLTagg = 0

If Control.intLBoSNR = 1 Then
        strQuery = "SELECT count(TIS_LAGERSPIEGEL.LT) FROM TIS_AGG_SNR " & _
                    "LEFT JOIN TIS_LAGERSPIEGEL ON TIS_AGG_SNR.SNR_KARTE=TIS_LAGERSPIEGEL.SNR_KARTE " & _
                    "WHERE TIS_AGG_SNR.LB= """ & strStoreArea & """;"
        Set recTmp = db.OpenRecordset(strQuery)

        If Not IsNull(recTmp.Fields(0)) Then lngTotalLTagg = recTmp.Fields(0)
    ElseIf Control.intLBoSNR = 2 Then
        strQuery = "SELECT count(TIS_LAGERSPIEGEL.LT) FROM SELECTED_SNR " & _
                   "LEFT JOIN TIS_LAGERSPIEGEL ON SELECTED_SNR.SNR_SPEICHER = TIS_LAGERSPIEGEL.SNR_SPEICHER;"
        Set recTmp = db.OpenRecordset(strQuery)

        If Not IsNull(recTmp.Fields(0)) Then lngTotalLTagg = recTmp.Fields(0)
    End If
```

I don't quite understand what I get from `recTmp = db.OpenRecordset(strQuery)`
and what from `recTmp.Fields(0)`

I really hope somebody can help me, thanks!

PS.: db is my database from Access

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read [ask], then improve question(edit)! If you don't know, start read the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/office-client-development) (known as RTFM).

Comment: What don't you understand? If you don't know the function, google, then read the documentation for it. If you did that and still don't understand, state clearly the expected and observed behaviors and explain the difference. It might do you some good to experiment a bit with a simplified version of the code to isolate the behaviors in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With so little imagination or fantasy, you will meet many bumps.

However, this *opens(a)recordset* based on the query:

```
Set recTmp = db.OpenRecordset(strQuery)
```

and this reads the value of the first field of the current row:

```
lngTotalLTagg = recTmp.Fields(0)
```